# Nested if (or) in array for heading cell in Google Sheets is only validating the first 2 conditions

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets

I am trying to make a formula in Google Sheets that works as an array in the first cell of a column, displaying the title of the column, and also triggers a text change in the rest of the column depending on a number range from another cell. All this for an array that works along data from Google form.

So far I previously had  this working but you need to manually drag it down:

```
=IF(K1=0, "Finalizado",IF(AND(K1>=0.000001, K1<0.49),"En Tiempo", IF(AND(K1>=0.5, K1<0.75),"Pendiente", iF(AND(K1>=0.75, K1<1), "Retrasado",iF(AND(K1>=1), "Fuera de Tiempo", "Undefined")))))
```

Then, when I make it into an array that is set on the first cell of the column it only validates the first two conditions, so it only shows either 'finalizado' if the referenced cell is 0 or 'En tiempo', not to mention that once it gets to a point where there is no more referenced data, it just keeps repeating 'finalizado on each next cell.

```
={"Estatus";ArrayFormula(IF(K2:K=0, "Finalizado",IF(or(K2:K>=0.000001, K2:K<0.49),"En Tiempo",IF(and(K2:K>=0.5, K2:K<0.75),"Pendiente",iF(and(K2:K>=0.75, K2:K<1), "Retrasado",iF(AND(K2:K>=1), "Fuera de Tiempo"))))))}
```

I think the problem might be around the third if.

Comment: arrayformula cant work with AND and OR so that needs to be converted to 0/1 logic with +/-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(K1:K), 
 IF(K1:K=0, "Finalizado",
 IF((K1:K>=0.000001) * (K1:K<0.49), "En Tiempo", 
 IF((K1:K>=0.5) * (K1:K<0.75), "Pendiente", 
 IF((K1:K>=0.75) * (K1:K<1), "Retrasado",
 IF(K1:K>=1, "Fuera de Tiempo", "Undefined"))))), ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you. It worked perfectly.

As a note for anyone coming here later, if your referenced cel K also is in a column with another array and you try test values, its going to give you a REF error in K1. It's fixed by erasing your test value and letting the array run, so if you want to test  the array you need to change the KI:K to perhaps a L1:L  and add values in L to test out.

Answer (score 0):

```
={"Estatus"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(K2:K), 
 IF(K2:K=0, "Finalizado", 
 IF((K2:K>=0.5) * (K2:K<0.75), "Pendiente", 
 IF((K2:K>=0.75) * (K2:K<1), "Retrasado",
 IF(K2:K>=1, "Fuera de Tiempo",
 IF((K2:K>=0.000001) + (K2:K<0.49), "En Tiempo", "Undefined"))))), ))}
```

[image: 0]